# minikube start error exit status 1

Tags: minikube

Here is my error when i "minikube start " in Aliyun.

What I did:

1. `minikube delete`
2. `kubectl config use-context minikube`
3. `minikube start --vm-driver=none`

Aliyun(The 3rd Party Application Server) could not install VirtualBox or KVM,
so I tried to start it with `--vm-driver=none`.

```
[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]#  minikube delete 
Deleting local Kubernetes cluster...
Machine deleted.
[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]#  kubectl config use-context minikube
Switched to context "minikube".
[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]#  minikube start --vm-driver=none
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E0618 16:06:56.885163     500 start.go:294] Error starting cluster:  kubeadm init error sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI  running command: : running command: sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 
 output: [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.10.0
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube" could not be reached
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube" lookup minikube on 100.100.2.138:53: no such host
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
Flag --admission-control has been deprecated, Use --enable-admission-plugins or --disable-admission-plugins instead. Will be removed in a future version.
[certificates] Using the existing ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Using the existing apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1]
[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [minikube] and IPs [172.31.4.34]
[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/var/lib/localkube/certs/"
a kubeconfig file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf" exists already but has got the wrong CA cert
: running command: sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 
.: exit status 1
```

Versions of components:

```
[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]# minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.0

[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]# uname -a
Linux iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@iZj6c68brirvucbzz5yyunZ home]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.4", GitCommit:"5ca598b4ba5abb89bb773071ce452e33fb66339d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-06T08:13:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Why Minikube exit with the status 1?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to cleanup all traces after the previous unsuccessful `minikube` start. It should help with mismatch certificate issue.

```
rm -rf ~/.minikube ~/.kube /etc/kubernetes
```

Then try to start minikube again.

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

If you still running into errors, try to follow my "happy path":
(This was tested on fresh GCP instance with Ubuntu 16 OS on board)

```
# become root
sudo su

# turn off swap
swapoff -a
# edit /etc/fstab and comment swap partition.

# add repository key
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
# add repository
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
# update repository cache
apt-get update
# install some software 
apt-get -y install ebtables ethtool docker.io apt-transport-https kubelet kubeadm kubectl

# tune sysctl
cat <<EOF >>/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1
EOF
sudo sysctl --system

# download minikube
wget https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v0.28.0/minikube-linux-amd64

# install minikube
chmod +x minikube-linux-amd64
mv minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/minikube

# start minikube
minikube start --vm-driver=none

---This is what you should see----------
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
===================
WARNING: IT IS RECOMMENDED NOT TO RUN THE NONE DRIVER ON PERSONAL WORKSTATIONS
        The 'none' driver will run an insecure kubernetes apiserver as root that may leave the host vulnerable to CSRF attacks

When using the none driver, the kubectl config and credentials generated will be root owned and will appear in the root home directory.
You will need to move the files to the appropriate location and then set the correct permissions.  An example of this is below:

        sudo mv /root/.kube $HOME/.kube # this will write over any previous configuration
        sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
        sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.kube

        sudo mv /root/.minikube $HOME/.minikube # this will write over any previous configuration
        sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
        sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.minikube

This can also be done automatically by setting the env var CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
Loading cached images from config file.
-------------------

#check the results
$ kubectl get nodes

NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
minikube   Ready     master    18s       v1.10.0

$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running   0          10m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-p99gv               3/3       Running   0          10m
kube-system   kube-proxy-hlfc8                        1/1       Running   0          10m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-scdf9   1/1       Running   0          10m
kube-system   storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running   0          10m
```